# using android ndk to call native function from .so file

Tags: android, android-ndk

I found instructions for how to link and use c/c++ code in Android by utilizing the NDK. But I'm searching how call function from third party .so .

Comment: Just link it as static library in makefile

Comment: As i don't know much about it. Can you explain how to link as static library?

Comment: [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp#javacpp) can make this process easier for you...

Answer (score 0):

For example your prebuilt library is called "libmy.so"

In the project folder of the project you want to use it:

1) create libmy folder in jni folder (`jni/libmy`)

2) copy your `libmy.so` here

Then, just create a `jni/libmy/Android.mk` file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libmy
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libmy.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Now in your jni/Android.mk you can write:

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libmy
```

Then when you do ndk-build, it will copy this library in to libs/armeabi/

After that you can use this library in your C++ code.

Comment: it is not copying this library to libs/armeabi/ after ndk-bulid

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put the .so in your libs/armeabi-v7a folder (or whatever other architecture you have compiled for, like armeabi, x86 etc.) and Eclipse will automatically see it and integrate it into the APK.

Then to access any native functions from the .so in your Java code, you just have to declare it as a native function at the top of your class. For example

protected static native void AKUAppInitialize ();

which can then be called anywhere later in the code like

AKUAppInitialize();

Comment: whenever i put my .so in libs/armeabi and it got disappeared after compiling :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your NDK part if you have the source code: look at [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_dev_intro.html#android-dev-intro)